# How do I use the scoreboard command to join a team?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make it so that when a player steps on a pressure plate it activates a series of command blocks.

1. `/scoreboard teams join <team>`
2. `/tp @p <x> <y> <z>`

I am able to make the second command work but the join team command isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [The Wiki is your friend.](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Scoreboard)

Comment: @Texenox - It's also your friend :). You should write an answer, linking to the Wiki as a reference :)

Comment: @Robotnik Okay. I'll figure something out for an answer, in that case. Bookmarked.

Answer (score 6):

When used in a command block, you need to specify the player(s) that you want to add to the team. The full syntax of the subcommand is:

```
scoreboard teams join <team> [player]
```

For your case, the following command should work:

```
scoreboard teams join <team> @p
```

(Remembering to replace `<team>` with the name of an actual team)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/scoreboard teams join <team name> {USERNAME}` This is for a player to use. I do not think this command could be run from a command block. Correct me if I'm wrong, But when I still had a vanilla server, we always had a staff put a player on a team.

Answer (score 0):

In the later versions (1.14.2+) /team isn't compatible with command blocks at all, so you can't really do much if you're looking into non-manual mini-game sorting.

Comment: Evidence for this claim?

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, you need to create a team with /scoreboard teams create (team) before using /scoreboard teams join and for connecting them to the pressure plate do this: [image: Picture of pressure plate with command blocks.]

Sources:
Own knowledge

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a bit more information? Your answer is unclear.

Answer (score -2):

As of Minecraft 1.13, you don't "use the scoreboard command to join a team", as [`/team`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/team) is its own command, disconnected from the scoreboard entirely.